# Trying to serialize and unserialze a Binary search tree to a file

Tags: java

I am trying to find a way to use these methods to save and restore a binary search tree that contains names and phone numbers in each node.

I am just very lost and how to go about doing this.

```
  'public void save(String fileName) {
    // TODO : implement this method.
    // save bst to its original shape.
}

public void restore(String fileName) {
    // TODO : implement this method.
    // restore bst from a file, if file exists.
    // do nothing, otherwise.
    File fichier = new File(fileName);
    if (fichier.exists()) {

    }
}'
```

Comment: What's wrong with standard serialization?

Comment: NB Don't call `File.exists()`. You're about to call new `FileInputStream()` anyway, which will throw `FileNotFoundException` if the file isn't there. It's going to do that test anyway whether you like it or not. Don't double up.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

check out JsonWriter and JsonReader from json-io library https://code.google.com/p/json-io/

you'll have to add java-io jar to your path, preferably using maven or download it from the Downloads tab